# Jquery Resize: how to check if a screen has been resized at any point

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, frontend, web-frontend

I'm using the jQuery .resize() event listener, and understand how to use it to trigger an action whenever the screen is re-sized. However, I'm wondering if there is a way in jQuery to allow one not just to listen for when a screen is re-sized, but to check whether or not a screen has been re-sized at all over the course of a user's session.

Comment: Store a flag when resize was triggered in session storage/ local storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple approach you could log the initial viewport dimensions and compare them later. `$(window).width();` and `$(window).height();` will give you the dimensions.